# Creating service library in JavaScript, how to export functions from one file in another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, import, module

So I have this code in an identity service.

```
export function sumbitLogin(username, password) {
    console.log(username, password);
}
```

So without having to import every service I need in every component, I want to be able to import just one service library that will give my component access to every service it needs.

So I've created a js library file that just contains

```
export * as Identity from "./identity-service";
```

So that I can then import that one file from my component as

```
import * as Services from '../../services/service-library';
```

It doesn't seem to take this as it gives me this error

```
./src/services/service-library.js 1:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export * as Identity from "./identity-service";
```

I've tried exporting it 10 different ways but I can never reach `submitLogin()`. Does anyone see what I'm missing? I feel like another loader is uneccessary but if it's not I don't know which loader I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to do it is create an *index.js* file in the *services* folder where you can re-export all services:

```
import * as Identity from './identity-service';
import * as Logger from './logger-service';
...

export {
  Identity,
  Logger,
};
```

Then you can use that file directly:

```
import * as Services from '../services';

const { Identity, Logger } = Services;

Identity.sumbitLogin(username, password);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and I like the syntax, very clean and easy to understand. Thank you so much